# os.walk ignore directorys and its content

Tags: os.walk

i'm trying to ignore some directory and the files in it in specific path and this is my code

```
    x = open(wbCMD, 'a')
x.write('set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path% c:/Program Files/WinRAR/\n')
x.write('Rar.exe a -r "Backup.rar" -m5 -ep1')
chkdict = {}
setdef = chkdict.setdefault
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(foldername):
    if ignoreddirs in dirs:
        continue
    for file in files:
        ext = path.splitext(file)[1]
        if ext in ignored:
            continue
        if not ext in chkdict:
            print("%s" % setdef(ext,ext))
            x.write(" *%s" % setdef(ext,ext))
x.write(" *makefile *Depend *readme\npause")
x.close
del chkdict
```

ignoreddirs array looks like this

```
ignoreddirs = ["bin"]
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: "ignore directorys and its content".... it just ignore the directorys ... which i'm not using at all ... i mean the script is just writing the extensions and there are some folders have files that i don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dirs` and `ignoreddirs` are both lists of strings. Therefore, `dirs` does not contain `ignoreddirs`. It may, however contain some of its elements. One way to check this would be to check their intersection:

```
if len(set(ignoreddirs).intersection(set(dirs))) > 0:
    continue
```